# Apache iBatis SqlSession's update method

Tags: mybatis, ibatis

Is the `update` method of interface `SqlSession` in *apache ibatis*, **asynchronous or synchronous(spinlock/sleeping on it)**?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: Once from the java code, I call the update method, is the call synchronous or async? If sync, does the process wait in spinlock or sleeps on the call to return ?